# Converting a color image to grayscale issue in OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm facing a problem, when I'm trying to convert a color image to a grayscale. The error is: "bad argument (array should be CvMat or IplImage) in cvGetSize", but I can manage to load the original color image and display it, when I'm commenting all the lines, which are related to the grayscale one. How can I fix this error ?.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Loading the color image 
    IplImage* frame = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg");
    //Converting the color image to grayscale
    IplImage* grayframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCvtColor(frame, grayframe, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //Creating a window for color image
    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //Creating a window for grayscale image
    cvNamedWindow("Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    // Showing the color image
    cvShowImage("Example1", frame);
    // Showing the grayscale image
    cvShowImage("Example2", grayframe);
    //Showeing for X seconds
    cvWaitKey(2000);
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
    cvReleaseImage(&grayframe);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bro, use cv::Mat with imread to acquire the images. Also spend a couple of hours [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why Iplimage ?

try with Mat, if you would like to extend the examples in future.

```
Mat image = imread("lena.jpg");
Mat gray;
cvtColor(image,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

this would with ease, will give you gray scale image.

But, if there is a specific reason to use C api, then,
the problem is at

```
IplImage* grayframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

I don't know the exact reason for that, but, I could give you an alternative to run your code.

```
int x= frame->width, y=frame->height;
IplImage* grayframe = cvCreateImage(cvSize(x,y), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

Tyr it, it might work for you

Comment: even i am stuck with same error from last 2 days, dont know what to do